# DeathStar maintenance

Tags: star-wars, cleaning

I have a LEGO Deathstar and have already built stage one of four. However, I haven't been able to get to it lately and it has become rather dusty. How should I clean it? And I travel a lot, so is there any way I can carry it with me by flight without dismantling it?

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix : Hahaha thanks. Funny that Darth Vader is cleaning the Death Star ;)

Answer (score 0):

Which Death Star?

Either way, I can't imagine trying to travel with either Death Star model that LEGO has produced.

Removing dust can be done with a mini-vacuum or some sort of blower, like a hair drier. Canned air is advised against as it has icky propellants that get on your bricks.

Comment: Ah Alright. By the way, why was this marked as duplicate? I understand that the method is similar... but I asked for a travel case too.

Comment: @Artemisia - It's better to ask two single questions especially when they are very distinct, rather than have one question with two very different aspects which might result in two people answering each part, and no real way to mark either one as "the answer". For some suggestions on transporting models, see [this question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/129/56)