# How do I move assembled LEGO sets?

Tags: transport

How do I move large sets put together?  We do not have the instructions or original box.  We are moving from one home to another.

Comment: See [this question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/64/52) for advice on where to get instruction booklets for the inevitable repairs.

Comment: Carefully. Ba dum tish.

Comment: Take a photo before moving models. If bits fall off, you'll know where they go.

Comment: Some of the advice in [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-do-you-plan-large-structures-for-easy-and-safe-transport-to-shows/339#339) may be useful although doesn't apply to everything.

Answer (score 8):

When I was a child and our family moved, I took apart the larger sets into easily manageable pieces. For example, taking off wings and antennas of starships. Then I tetrised all the pieces into shoe boxes and other closable, stackable containers that could then be transported by almost any means. This method required reassembly at the destination but thanks to the planned breakdown it was easy to do. If I remember correctly the boxes were lined with cloth to dampen vibrations and prevent scratches, so nothing really got damaged.

Answer (score 6):

We moved the Death Star into our office by hand. When we needed to move it to another place, we use a plastic bag to wrap it up and put it in the backseat of the car, so that even if little parts fell off, we could still find it in the bag, instead of trying to find it in the car.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of suggestions:

- Put them in plastic bins/bags or some other type of container, so that any pieces that come off will not be lost
- separate models if you can; having pieces from different models mixed together will make them harder to repair
- remove sections beforehand that are likely to fall off; put them in separate containers/bags
- label all containers/bags
- use some sort of insulation, such as inflated plastic baggies, small balloons, packing peanuts, or blankets to wrap the models in to protect them from any impacts

These protected my collection during a move, so they should keep yours pretty safe.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap the sets in stretch wrap to keep the parts together and then in bubble wrap to protect from external forces.